# Collapsing cardinal $\lambda$ to $\omega$ by Cohen foricng

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing

Does this forcing notion:
$$\mathbb{P}=\{f:f \text{ is a finite function from }\lambda \text{ to }\{0,1\}\}$$
collapse $\lambda$ to $\omega$ in $V[G]$?

Where can I consult this fact in Kunen's book IIP?
How can this $\mathbb{P}$ collapse $\lambda$ to $\omega$ if $$\Vdash_P"2^{\aleph_0}=\lambda"$$ (see the snippet below)
which implies $$\Vdash_P"\lambda > \omega"$$
[image]

Comment: This forcing has the c.c.c., so it preserves all cardinals. In particular it does not collapse $\lambda$ to $\omega$. What it does is that it collapses $2^{\aleph_0}$ to $\lambda$.

Comment: I realize that the wording of my previous comment is a little bad. I said that it doesn't collapse anything, yet it "collapses" $2^{\aleph_0}$ to $\lambda$. Here I don't mean that we are collapsing the ordinal $(2^{\aleph_0})^V$ but I mean that if we compute $2^{\aleph_0}$ in $V[G]$, we get $\lambda$.

Comment: @Shervin: What you mean to say is that it increases $2^{\aleph_0}$ to be at least $\lambda$.

Comment: @Asaf, yeah. That's what I meant to say. Yet I feel my second comment doesn't do it justice either. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @AsafKaragila What was $2^{\aleph_0}$ before in $V$ if in the generic extension $V[G]$ we have it is at least $\lambda$ ? Was it greater or lesser before forcing than $\lambda$ ?

Comment: I feel like combining the rest of the information on in the comments you should be able to answer this question yourself...

Comment: @AsafKaragila No I cannot. Can you kindly still help me ?

Comment: $(2^{\omega})^V\le (\lambda^{\omega})^V=(2^{\omega})^{V[G]}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The snippet says $\Vdash_P "2^{\aleph_0}\geq \lambda"$ and **not** $\lambda^\omega$.

Comment: @user122424 There's no contradiction there - DanielWainfleet is correct. In particular, note that his comment calculates $(2^\omega)^{V[G]}$ *exactly*, while the result above merely gives a lower bound (later on in Kunen you'll see the exact value).

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand Noah's answer that you accepted. Ccc forcing will not collapse cardinals so it won't be less.

Comment: Seconding @AsafKaragila's comment, you should un-accept my answer until you understand the reasoning behind it, not just the fact at the end (otherwise having an accepted answer will dissuade people from giving further, and possibly better, answers to this question).

Comment: I think that the thing which is confusing you is that Cohen forcing changes cardinal arithmetic, not cardinals. $V$ and $V[G]$ have exactly the same cardinals, but $V[G]$ contains a new surjection $2^\omega\to\lambda$ which is not in $V$

Comment: And elaborating on @AlessandroCodenotti's comment, *other* forcings can indeed change cardinals (e.g. the Levy collapse). Note that - if we restrict attention to forcings which preserve cardinals - addition and multiplication will never be affected, it's only the "higher arithmetic" (exponentiation, cofinality if you consider that arithmetic, etc.) which can be modified by cardinal-preserving forcing (and it doesn't make sense to me to ask whether a *non*-cardinal-preserving forcing preserves cardinal arithmetic - a bit "cart-before-the-horse").

Comment: @NoahSchweber In forcing, I'm never convinced with definiteness about the issues in question. I treat it only as more or less probable on what is discussed. Noah's answer sounds quite probable to me so I can keep acceptance. This is because so many variables come into the consideration that there is always a possibility of being on the wrong way.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, what do you mean that **won't be less** ?

Comment: @user122424 I think what Asaf means is that the cardinality of the continuum won’t be less in the forcing extension than it is in the ground model (since this forcing doesn’t collapse cardinals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding some discussion in the comments about the likely source of OP's confusion into an answer...

There are two distinct things that can happen in the forcing extension that can potentially impact the value of $\mathfrak c.$

1. **The cardinality of the reals in $V$ can collapse.** In other words, $\mathfrak c^V$, defined as the unique least ordinal such that there is an $f\in V$ that is a bijection $\mathfrak c^V\to P(\omega)^V$ (where $P(\omega)^V$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ that are in $V$), can cease to be a cardinal in $V[G]$. The way this happens is that $V[G]$ has a bijection between $\mathfrak c^V$ and a smaller ordinal (one that obviously can't be in $V$ since $\mathfrak c^V$ is a cardinal in $V$). So in other words, we have $|\mathfrak c^V|^{V[G]} < \mathfrak c^V.$
2. **There can be reals in $V[G]$ that are not in $V.$** In other words, $P(\omega)^V\subsetneq P(\omega)^{V[G]}.$ In this case it is perfectly possible that $P(\omega)^{V[G]}$ has a larger cardinality than $P(\omega)^V$ in $V[G].$ (Note that even though $P(\omega)^V$ is defined in reference to $V$, it is a set in $V[G]$ simply because $V\subset V[G]$, so it makes perfect sense to talk about its cardinality in $V[G].$)

A key distinction is that while $\mathfrak c$ is defined as the cardinality of a set meeting some definition, by contrast, $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_{17}$ (for example) are defined simply by their position in the cardinal hierarchy (one can either think of $1$ and $17$ as stand-ins for fixed ordinals or note that $1$ and $17$ are absolute so it doesn't matter if we think of them as defined). Thus these latter two are only subject to the first kind of disturbance, not the second kind.

In a c.c.c. forcing like your example, it can be shown that the first kind of disturbance cannot occur. For any $\kappa$ that is a cardinal in $V$ there are no new bijections in $V[G]$ between $\kappa$ and a smaller ordinal. In other words, a cardinal in $V$ remains a cardinal in $V[G].$ This means we do not have to distinguish between $|\cdot|^V$ and $|\cdot|^{V[G]},$ nor do we have to distinguish between $\aleph_1^V$ and $\aleph_1^{V[G]}.$ So the change the value of $\mathfrak c$ is entirely driven by the fact that there are more subsets of $\mathbb N$ in the forcing extension. Assuming CH holds in the ground model and $|\lambda|>\aleph_1,$ we have $$|P(\omega)^{V[G]}|\ge \lambda > \omega_1= |P(\omega)^V|.$$

---

An instructive contrasting example is to force with countable partial bijections between $P(\omega)^V$ and $\aleph_1^V.$ This forcing notion is not c.c.c., but is $\omega$-closed, which is another nice property with very different implications; for instance, it implies that no new maps $\omega\to V$ exist in $V[G].$ This means that $P(\omega)^V=P(\omega)^{V[G]}$ since new reals would mean new maps $\omega\to 2.$ It also means $\aleph_1^{V} = \aleph_1^{V[G]}$, but for a very different reason than in the previous example: a collapsing bijection $\omega\to \aleph_1^V$ would be a new map $\omega\to V.$ Note also that this same reasoning doesn't extend to $\aleph_{17}$: it won't be collapsed to be countable, but it could be collapsed to some smaller uncountable cardinal.

In fact, provided our ground model *violates* the CH, a cardinal will collapse in this forcing, namely the cardinality of the reals in the ground model. The generic set gives a bijection between $P(\omega)$ and $\aleph_1$ (no superscript needed on either of these per the last paragraph), so CH holds in $V[G].$ Thus we have $$\mathfrak c^{V[G]}=|P(\omega)^{V[G]}|^{V[G]} = \aleph_1 < |P(\omega)^V|^V =\mathfrak c^V.$$

(I left the superscripts on the $P(\omega)$ just for emphasis... as mentioned before, they are the same set in this particular case, in contrast to the previous example of Cohen forcing where there are new reals in the forcing extension.)

So for instance if we had $\mathfrak c=\aleph_{17}$ in $V$, then $|\aleph_{17}^V|^{V[G]} = \aleph_1^{V[G]},$ so $\aleph_{17}$ in $V$ has collapsed to have cardinality $\aleph_1$ in $V[G].$

Comment: +1. I made a minor change - feel free to revert if disapproved.

Answer (score 5):

No, Cohen forcing does not collapse *any* cardinals. Specifically, no **c.c.c.** forcing will ever collapse cardinals. A forcing $\mathbb{P}$ is c.c.c. iff $\mathbb{P}$ has no uncountable antichains (remember that "antichain" in the context of forcing means a set of *incompatible* rather than merely *incomparable* elements). This is a standard result, which appears in Kunen explicitly (I don't have my copy on my so I can't give a reference number at the moment). The c.c.c.-ness of Cohen forcing is a consequence of the $\Delta$-system lemma, and both this lemma and its application appear in Cohen explicitly as well.

Meanwhile, it's worth noting that there are two ways that the lower bound $(2^{\aleph_0})^{V[G]}\ge\lambda$ could fail to be sharp:

- **We could have $(2^{\aleph_0})^V>\lambda$ already at the beginning.** Nothing says that we have to start with a model of CH (although when first introducing forcing we generally *do*, since all we know at that point is the relative consistency of ZFC+CH per Godel). Since c.c.c. forcings don't collapse cardinals, this will prevent $(2^{\aleph_0})^{V[G]}=\lambda$.
- **We could wind up with $cf(\lambda)^{V[G]}=\omega$ at the end.** Since ZFC proves $cf(2^{\aleph_0})>\omega$, this would mean that in $V[G]$ we can't possibly have $2^{\aleph_0}=\lambda$. Note that a priori to tell if this situation holds we need to look at cofinalities in $V[G]$, but it turns out that in this particular case this situation will arise exactly when $cf(\lambda)^V=\omega$: any c.c.c. forcing preserves cofinalities as well as cardinalities, by basically the same argument.

In light of the above - especially the second bulletpoint - you should be even more interested in the question of *exactly* computing $2^{\aleph_0}$ in $V[G]$. It turns out this is something that we can do without too much effort, the relevant term being "nice names" (and Kunen will treat them later on); the exact calculation is $(2^{\aleph_0})^{V[G]}=\vert\lambda^\omega\vert^V$, as DanielWainfleet commented.

---

Incidentally, *finiteness* of domain is crucial here. In general, if we force with partial functions from $\kappa$ to $\lambda$ with domain of cardinality $<\mu$, we may indeed collapse cardinals: e.g. forcing with *countable* partial functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_2$ will preserve $\omega_1$ but collapse $\omega_2$ *(preservation of $\omega_1$ follows from countable closure, and collapsing $\omega_2$ is a good exercise - I believe as above this all appears explicitly in Kunen)*.

There is an important principle at work here, which is often counterintuitive at first:

> Forcing with "larger" conditions generally adds **fewer** "small" sets!

In particular, forcing with finite partial functions adds reals while forcing with countable partial functions won't. This same point will come back with a vengeance when you look at **iterated** forcing in the context of the set theory of the reals, where finite support iterations turn out to be nasty while countable and full support iterations are quite tame.

Comment: What is the **size** of your partial functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_2$ that collapse $\omega_2$ to $\omega_1$ ?

Comment: @user122424 Whoops, omitted - fixed! As a cute aside, note that [even easy preservation facts tend to require a bit more than ZF](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139277/how-to-make-countably-closed-forcing-nice-without-choice).

Comment: Right. I've already asked that in comments above but I didn't get answer: is made $2^{\aleph_0}$ larger or lesser than before forcing so that after forcing $V[G] \models 2^{\aleph_0}\geq \lambda$ ? What do we force with in here: what is $\mathbb{P}$ to deal with the size $2^{\aleph_0}$ **after** forcing?

Comment: @user122424 I'm not sure I understand your question? Forcing only adds sets and c.c.c. forcings don't change cardinals (more precisely, statements of the form "$\alpha$ is the smallest ordinal such that there is a bijection from $\beta$ to $\alpha$" are preserved by forcing), so there's no sense in which Cohen forcing can "shrink" the continuum ...

Comment: Please see the theorem $4.1$ in the snippet in my OQ. They claim "we have shown that" $\Vdash_P "2^{\aleph_0}\geq \lambda"$ after forcing with **finite** functions from $\lambda$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @user122424 Yes, that's true. I don't understand how that relates to the question you're asking in your previous comment?

Comment: We must have changed either $\lambda$ **or** $2^{\aleph_0}$ to get that inequality, right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104937/discussion-between-noah-schweber-and-user122424).

Comment: I think the problem is that you are thinking of $2^{\aleph_0}$ as a fixed ordinal (like the cardinal $\omega_1$, for example) while it is actually just an abbreviation for "the cardinality of the set of reals". What the forcing does is add a lot of new reals, so in the extension, what we now call $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a completely different thing, namely the cardinality of what is now the set of reals. But the cardinality of what used to be $\mathbb R$ before the forcing has not changed at all.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo To be fair, the symbol "$\omega_1$" is as dangerous as "$2^{\aleph_0}$" after all.

Comment: @Noah But not in the context of cofinality preserving forcing. I used it on purpose. Once the hurdle of the reals is understood, then we can add nuance.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Personally I find it especially dangerous for exactly that reason - it quietly sets up a possible confusion to arise later. But of course this is a subjective pedgagogical question.